# Launch Espresso tests on several emulators

Tags: android, android-emulator, automated-tests, android-espresso

We want to test that an Android library works on all emulators from Android 9 to 25. To do it, we downloaded emulators from 9 to 25, created them one by one, and went within the loop of starting an emulator, passing the tests on its version and closing the emulator when the tests are green.

If one of my colleagues wants to do the same than me, he has to repeat all the manual process: download them all, create an emulator of every version, start it, launch the tests manually, stop it and go for the next emulator.

There's any way of automating the process? I know that the tests will last for several time, but we expect our best of the library we're going to release :·)

Comment: Have you looked at Test Orchestrator: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner.html#using-android-test-orchestrator

Answer (score 5):

One approach is to use `Fastlane` and in particular the `automated_test_emulator_run` plugin (https://github.com/AzimoLabs/fastlane-plugin-automated-test-emulator-run)

For example:

```
  lane :Automation_EmulatorRun_Gradle do
      automated_test_emulator_run(
        AVD_setup_path: "~/<path to your avd setup>/AVD_setup.json",
        gradle_task:"<your test task>"
      )
   end
```

Comment: Woaw, it smells sweet! :·) Going to try it for sure!

Comment: What programming language is that?

Comment: It's Fastlane 

Answer (score 2):

you could try also [spoon](https://github.com/square/spoon) by square that launch the instrumentation test to all devices visibles via `adb devices`

Comment: I think he's trying to automate the creation of emulators, not just running the tests.

Comment: if only want to automate that, a simple .sh will be enough

Comment: Yes, the idea behind the question is to know if there's something simpler than writing that simple .sh that automagically downloads a set of emulators and loop over starting the older one, launch the tests, close it, open the next emulator until all emulators are ok, and give a green if every suite was green.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked Swarmer? Seems to do just what you want

https://github.com/gojuno/swarmer

From their readme:

> Start multiple Android Emulators and wait for each to boot in parallel.